# American movie : a guy running in a rat maze

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was young late seventies. The movie, where reality is mixed with dreams and dreams become reality, is about a guy who is falling slowly into madness, as my child mind understood it.

Two scenes I remember the most are :

1 - an analogy with a rat's running through a maze as in a scientific experiment and the guy's running in the same maze, opening doors and falling in another corridor with many other doors.

2 - and a scene near the end I think : all along the movie the guy fantasizes about a woman in red, lying down on a board in front of his motel/house. This is a giant board, advertising for something I don't remember. And then, at the end, in one of his fantasies, he is very small and climbs the woman (who is alive) between her breasts.

The movie is in color and was made, I guess in the sixties or seventies.I'd really like to watch it with my now old eyes.

Comment: Can elaborate more on what science fiction or fantasy elements this film has? A man running through a maze and fantasizing about women seems pretty mundane...

Comment: @Skooba the whole movie is a fantasy where reality is mixed with dreams and dreams become reality. Now, if you are waiting for Godzilla to show up, for sure you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: _"I was young and did not need any money at the time, "_ not a native speaker here: I don't get if this is an expression to say the movie was bad, or if this is a joke about your current financial situation unrelated to the movie? In short: can you please rephrase?

Comment: Some of the elements fit [Charly (1968)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charly) specifically the maze and the hallucinations.